# assigning functions to variables in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

Hello i have a weird doubt..

MY code is

```
    def prints():
        print " I WILL DIE HEHE"

    def add(a,b):
        next = a
        print " Added sum is %d " % (next + b)
        next = prints()


    w = int(raw_input("Give a"))
    g = int(raw_input("Give b"))
    add(w,g)
```

Now the problem is why does the function prints() gets executed while i assign it to next i.e. next = prints(). I am little confused.

Comment: What did you expect to happen when you assigned `prints()` to `next`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you are calling it,

```
prints()
```

will execute where as

```
ne = prints
ne()
```

is assigning the name, and then calling the new name.

Noteback, I also call it `ne` as `next` shadows a builtin method

Answer (score 2):

The following:

```
next = prints()
```

calls `prints()`, and assigns the result to `next`. Since `prints()` doesn't explicitly return anything, it implicitly returns `None`, and thus `next` is set to `None`.

It is not entirely clear what you're expecting or trying to achieve, but it may be helpful to consider the following:

```
next = prints
```

What this does is assign the function object to `next`. It does not call the function, but allows it to be called as `next()`.